# HTTP Status 500 - unexpected token: , near line 1, column 129

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

The error is as follows:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: , near line 1, column 129 [Select partnumber, partdescription, invoicenumber, quantity from invoicedetails i, parts p WHERE i.invoicenumber in :invoiceList, i.partnumber = p.partNo AND quantity < 0 ]

I try to run the query and save the records in xlx file. But when I execute it returns error unexpected token. Am I writing a query in the right way?

The query is working fine on SQL workbench

Can you guys help me in solving the problem. Help is really appreciated.  Thanks

entity class

```
public class SpecialOrder {

    public String partdescription;

    public Integer invoicenumber;

    public String partnumber;

    public Integer quantity;

    public Integer year;

    public SpecialOrder() {
        super();
    }

    public SpecialOrder(Integer invoicenumber, String partnumber, Integer quantity, Integer year,
            String partdescription) {
        super();
        this.invoicenumber = invoicenumber;
        this.partnumber = partnumber;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.year = year;
        this.partdescription = partdescription;
    }

    public String getPartdescription() {

        return partdescription;
    }

    public Integer getInvoicenumber() {

        return invoicenumber;
    }

    public String getPartnumber() {

        return partnumber;
    }

    public Integer getQuantity() {

        return quantity;
    }

    public Integer getYear() {

        return year;
    }

    public void setPartdescription(String partdescription) {

        this.partdescription = partdescription;
    }

    public void setInvoicenumber(Integer invoicenumber) {

        this.invoicenumber = invoicenumber;
    }

    public void setPartnumber(String partnumber) {

        this.partnumber = partnumber;
    }

    public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {

        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void setYear(Integer year) {

        this.year = year;
    }
```

Controller Class

```
@RequestMapping("specialorder")
    public ModelAndView SpecialOrder(@RequestParam("invoiceno") String invoiceno, Model map, HttpSession session,
            ModelAndView mav) throws ConnectException {

        AppUser user = (AppUser) session.getAttribute("user");
        if (user == null) {
            throw new OrderNotFoundException();
        } else {

            List<Integer> invoiceNoList = new ArrayList();
            if (invoiceno.contains(",")) {
                String[] array = invoiceno.split(",");
                for (String s : array) {
                    invoiceNoList.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
                }
            } else {
                invoiceNoList.add(Integer.parseInt(invoiceno));
            }
            List<SpecialOrder> invoiceList = ordersService.getSpecialOrder(invoiceNoList);
            System.out.println("invoice list  = " + invoiceList);

            mav.clear();
            mav.setView(new SpecialOrderExcelView());
            // mav.setViewName("specialorderpage");
            mav.addObject("user", user);
            mav.addObject("branch", branch);
            mav.addObject("appcss", appcss);
            mav.addObject("sysdate", InsightUtils.getNewUSDate());
            mav.addObject("invoiceList", invoiceList);
        }
        return mav;

    }
```

Service Class

```
@Transactional
    public List<SpecialOrder> getSpecialOrder(List<Integer> invoiceList) throws ConnectException {

        List<SpecialOrder> getspecialorder = new ArrayList<>();

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        String hSql = "Select partnumber, partdescription, invoicenumber, quantity " + "from invoicedetails i, parts p "
                + "WHERE i.invoicenumber in :invoiceList, i.partnumber = p.partNo AND quantity < 0 ";

        Query query = session.createQuery(hSql);

        query.setParameterList("invoiceList", invoiceList);

        getspecialorder = query.list();

        session.flush();
        session.clear();

        return getspecialorder;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the query at https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/ which did not like the comma in place of AND (which is in fact at position 129 as in the error message you got) and expects `in` to be followed by something in parentheses (it also does not like the colon, but that's because it is SQL not HQL so does not understand the parameter). It does accept the following (without the colon, which I restored after).

```
Select
partnumber,
  partdescription,
  invoicenumber,
  quantity
from
  invoicedetails i,
  parts p
WHERE
  i.invoicenumber in (:invoiceList)
  AND i.partnumber = p.partNo
  AND quantity < 0
```

which I believe should work for you.